# Access Text from Textfield in Subview Loaded from Nib

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to have my `viewcontroller` (`PersonalListViewController`) which loads a `UITableView`. There is an `addPersonalItem` button on the bottom of the page. When a user presses the button, it loads a `UIView` (`AddItemView`) from a Nib file.

On the `AddItemView` there are two `UITextFields`. 1) How can I access the text entered in the field from the `PersonalListViewController` and 2) how will the `PersonalListViewController` know when the user has removed `AddItemView` from the screen (i.e. entered text on `AddItemView` and pressed Done) ?

**In PersonalListViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)addPersonalItem:(id)sender {

        NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddItemView" owner:self options:nil];
        UIView *mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.view addSubview:mainView];
}
```

**In AddItemView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AddItemView : UIView  {
    IBOutlet UITextField *itemNameTextField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *quantityTextField;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemNameTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *quantityTextField;

@end
```

**In AddItemView.m**

```
#import "AddItemView.h"

@implementation AddItemView

@synthesize itemNameTextField;
@synthesize quantityTextField;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,
Define a block in `AddItemView` by

```
typedef void (^completionBlock)(NSString *itemName, NSString *quantity);
```

add a property of this block

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) completionBlock completionCallback;
```

so, in 
**AddItemView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef void (^completionBlock)(NSString *itemName, NSString *quantity);

@interface AddItemView : UIView  {
    IBOutlet UITextField *itemNameTextField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *quantityTextField;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemNameTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *quantityTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) completionBlock completionCallback;

- (IBAction)completionButtonAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

Add a `UIButton` in `AddItemView` and in it's action implement a block like

```
- (IBAction)completionButtonAction:(id)sender {
     if (self.completionCallback != nil) {
         NSString *itemName = self.itemNameTextField.text;
         NSString *quantity = self. quantityTextField.text;
         self.completionCallback (itemName, quantity);
     }
}
```

**In PersonalListViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)addPersonalItem:(id)sender {

    NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddItemView" owner:self options:nil];
    AddItemView *mainView = (AddItemView *)[subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
    void (^completionBlock)(NSString *itemName, NSString *quantity) = ^(NSString *itemName, NSString *quantity){
        [self personalItemAddedWithItemName:itemName quantity:quantity];
    };
    mainView.completionCallback = completionBlock
    [self.view addSubview:mainView];
}


- (void)personalItemAddedWithItemName:(NSString *)itemName quantity:(NSString *)quantity {
    //add your code here
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but it never gets in the if statement in `completionButtonAction:(id)sender.` If I remove the if statement `if (self.completionCallback != nil)`, an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error appears

Comment: oh.. sorry.. I forgot to add `mainView. completionCallback = completionBlock`. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the text of a UITextField, use its `.text` property (e.g. myTextField.text). I would recommend adding a UIButton to the AddItemView, and add a target action to the button. In the method the button calls, you should use the text fields' text there. After that, you can do all the adding etc.

PS I also recommend using a method besides just addSubview. Maybe pushing it with an animation would be better.

Answer (score 1):

First to get the text from the uitextfield you can set tag for every text field in the subview and get the textfield instance using the same tag. Or you can assign the delegate of both textfield to PersonalListViewController and get the text entered.

To know whether the AddItemView is removed or not. If you hiding and showing the AddItemView on press of the bottom button, then you can check for `[<mainView> isHidden]` property of the view and do your logics. Or if you removing AddItemView from the PersonalListViewController, then you can have global instance AddItemView and check for the  and do your logics. If  instance is there then the view is there.

Comment: He has outlets pointing to the text fields, so the tag does not affect him in this case.